# How to get taxonomy term values?

Tags: 8, entities

In my user entity, I have a term reference. In that vocabulary, I have a regular field. How can I fetch that field's value? I tried the below in  devel/php to no avail.

```
$user = Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(17);
$dept = $user->field_department->entity;
\dpm($dept->field_administrator_e_mail->value);
```

My end goal is to send the email to the department's administrator when a user is created.

UPDATE: I also tried the below:

```
$user = Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(17);
$dept = $user->field_department;
\dpm($dept->name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing link is the `entity` function, which returns the referenced entity object:

`$host_entity->host_field->entity->remote_field->value`

Comment: I tried `entity` as well, no luck - updating question

Comment: It wasn't working because of the way I added the taxonomy term to the entity.  It works correctly now, thanks.